# Simulating color stops in gradients for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, gradient

I want to give a div a gradient with multiple color-stops, which IE's filter property does not support. Anyone have a creative workaround to simulate the color stops in IE?
I already thought of creating multiple divs right next to each other... anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: I think multiple divs with coordinated gradient colors is the best way (short of using images) to create 3+ color gradients.

Comment: @Julian, you might as well add this as an answer.

Comment: Have you looked at [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) -- it's a hack that gives IE the ability to use standard CSS gradients. Not sure if it does what you need, but it would certainly be easier to manage than those horrible `filter` properties.

Comment: @Spudley - PIE looks great, AND it only gets downloaded for IE which is a real plus not to slow down the already modern browsers. unfortunately, it doesnt (yet) accomodate multiple gradients

Comment: @esther h - oh well. In that case, I'd go with the multiple `<div>` solution as suggested elsewhere. But perhaps use PIE for them all the same (and maybe post multiple gradients as a feature-request on the PIE forums).

Comment: @Spudley - my mistake, I am reviewing CSS3PIE now and it appears to support multiple gradients, yay!

Comment: Added the Pie solution as an answer. I totally missed this in the comments and ended up spending time implementing multiple divs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple divs with coordinated gradient colors is the best way (short of using images) to create 3+ color gradients.  See fiddle below for a working test:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hauhx/

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to use a background image as a fallback for browsers (as Opera and IE) that don't support CSS gradients.

Answer (score 2):

Or use CSS3 PIE. Way easy.

From [Setting linear gradient's starting and ending position in MSIE 9 and older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106627/setting-linear-gradients-starting-and-ending-position-in-msie-9-and-older)

```
div {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);

    -pie-background: linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Update: if the div has a top margin then it seems to do away with it. At least in my case. Don't know if it's a combination of two things.