# CSS tricks: underline with alpha-gradient on both ends

Tags: css

I need to underline my elements (menu items) with a line which has an gradient on BOTH ends.
It can't simply be a graphic (even stretched one), since the width of elements may vary significantly.

The desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

What I did, was to create a line, 1000px wide, with gradient on both ends, then append following HTML `<div><div class="right">&nbsp;</div></div>` to every element to be underlined.
The CSS is following

```
        #navmenu li div
        {               
            height: 1px;
            background-image: url('images/1000glight.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;                                       
        }
        
        
        #navmenu li div.right
        {
            width:35px;
            float: right;
            background-position: -965px 0;              
            background-image: url('images/1000glight.png');
            background-color: #212121;
        }
```

This however is not truly alpha. I need to specify the background color of "right-side" div in order to "cover" the image (1000px line) which is below.

Any ideas how could I improve it, keeping pure CSS?

Comment: Are you willing to sacrifice cross-browser compatibility? Or does it have to work in all browsers?

Comment: it has to be cross browser ;) not extremely of course, IE6 shall be ignored forever! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the border-image gradient CSS3.

```
div {
    width:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-image: 
           -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%) 0 0 100% 0/0 0 15px 0 stretch;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/TBs7a/).

This will only work with Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari etc). There should be some vendor specific equivalents.

Comment: Looks great in Chrome, less so in Firefox

Comment: I know the CSS3 trick, but I'd like to keep "some" cross-browser compatibility at least.

Answer (score 5):

Using an approach similar to this, with the gradient being the background image of a wrapping `div` with `padding-bottom` to show only the lower part of the background:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">Some Text!</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrap {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    /* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0%, #000 25%, #000 75%, #fff 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0%, #000 25%, #000 75%, #fff 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0%, #000 25%, #000 75%, #fff 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(0.25, #000), color-stop(0.75, #000), color-stop(1, #fff));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #fff 0%, #000 25%, #000 75%, #fff 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(right, #fff 0%, #000 25%, #000 75%, #fff 100%);
}

.content {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Works, but does omit IE<10; which might be do-able with some kind of filter, but that'll take more reading before I can post such.

[JS Fiddle demo of current implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UHcut/).

Unfortunately the DX.transform option doesn't appear able to allow for multiple stops that the above uses, reference: [Simulating color stops in gradients for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848475/simulating-color-stops-in-gradients-for-ie)

So, perhaps you'd have to use a background-image fallback for IE<10, which is far less than ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an empty div with a CSS3 Gradient... check out the presets here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - of course you'll have to change the orientation of the gradient.  I use this a lot for similar issues.  It's a great alternative to images.