# Setting linear gradient's starting and ending position in MSIE 9 and older

Tags: internet-explorer, css, filter, gradient

I have this CSS

```
background-image: linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);
```

with -moz, -o, -webkit, -ms (for IE10) prefixes.

I need to get this behaviour for older IEs using MSIE's filter.

I can do this

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#F17B19', gradientType='1');
```

But in previous case it behaves as

```
background-image: linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255),rgb(241,123,25));
```

or

```
background-image: linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 0% ,rgb(241,123,25) 100%);
```

Is there a way (**without using multiple divs**) to accomplish setting starting and ending point of a gradient (in this case 25% and 75%) using MSIE's CSS filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's completely impossible to do it with `filter`.

However, you can do it using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which uses JavaScript.

It's relatively painless:

```
div {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);

    -pie-background: linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: For IE9 and newer, you can use an SVG gradient.