# How do I modify IE Gradient CSS to use height and a third color?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, styles, stylesheet, linear-gradients

I have the following CSS for Gradients:

For IE 8-9

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d7d6d2',]
endColorstr='#f9ffff', GradientType=1);
/* IE 8–9 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d7d6d2',
endColorstr='#f9ffff', GradientType=1)";
```

For IE 10

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7d6d2 0%,#f9ffff 437px,#ffffff 100%);
```

For the IE 10 version I have 3 colors.  The first two create the gradient and the third color, which is #ffffff, shows the rest of the page in white color when the gradient has ended.  And the 437px defines the height of the gradient.

How can I modify the code for IE 8-9 for CSS Gradients so I can achieve what I have with the IE 10 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do gradients on IE8/9 is to use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

This is a Javascript polyfill library that implements the standard CSS gradient syntax into old versions of IE. (it also does a few other features like `border-radius`).

Simply download the Pie.htc file and add it to your site as per the instructions, and you can start using standard CSS gradients in IE 6-9.

To directly answer your question: CSS3Pie's gradients do support gradient colour stops. (But even without that, the improved syntax over `-ms-filter` is enough motivation for me to want to use it)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support gradient stops. You can only use two colors for a given element (such as a div or button).

As for IE9, you can accomplish this via a svg gradient such as this:

```
/* SVG as background image (IE9/Chrome/Safari/Opera) */ 
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

Microsoft has a decent SVG gradient generator [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/).

If that does not appeal to you, you can simulate the stops, which has already been discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848475/simulating-color-stops-in-gradients-for-ie).