# multi color start and stop background css property in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I woud like to use color start and stop to set the background property with multiple colors in IE 9.

I would like to set this background for a diw wich contains already divs and I would like to color the div with multiple colors in a horizontal way from left to right.

I have se en something that might help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849330/2401221

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think better for you to use CSS3 PIE

```
div {
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(360deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);

  -pie-background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(255,255,255) 25% ,rgb(241,123,25) 75%);
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```